# Is Java 7 supported on Tridion CMS 2011, sp1?

Tags: 2011, java

Can I upgrade my Java to version 7, from version 6? I thought I have read that Java 7 does not work with Tridion CMS 2011, SP1?

Comment: Java 7 will indeed not work with Tridion 2011. Tridion 2013 supports Java 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java 7 is supported since Tridion 2013.

Answer (score 1):

According to the online documentation, the following Java versions are supported:

[Content Manager](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_AF0D082F0D3E45F38C7653BB68A09ABB) (requires login): **Java (JRE or JDK) 6.0, 32-bit edition**
*(Java is only used for publishing and searching in the Content Manager)*

[Content Delivery](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_97BB43152C35488C843676F335B78099) (requires login): **Java 6.0, 32-bit or 64-bit edition**

As Eric says, Java 7 is supported (and recommended) in Tridion 2013 but not supported for Tridion 2011 (incl. SP1).

Java 5.0 will work with Tridion 2011, but is deprecated.

### UPDATE [11/07/2013]

It may also be worth looking at DanielGLB's [What versions of Java are supported and proven to work for Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1?](http://goo.gl/ZVfyL) question too.

Comment: Java6 Downloads here, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html