# Audience manager HandlerBase ClassNotFoundException

Tags: 2011, audience-manager

We have a successful implementation of audience manager, where a link in the e-mail points to a page on the site. This link works most of the time, but after a while we get the Error below. Resetting IIS does solve the issue temporarily.

Because this issue is hard to reproduce it would be good to hear if someone else has solved this issue.

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: ClassNotFoundException 
Exception message: com.tridion.marketingsolution.tracking.HandlerBase
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.marketingsolution.tracking.HandlerBase
    at com.codemesh.classloader.ExtensibleClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.codemesh.classloader.ExtensibleClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.codemesh.classloader.ExtensibleClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.codemesh.bootstrap.JarInputStreamBootstrapper.forName(Unknown Source)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.init()
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.get_JObject()
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init()
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_MethodPtr()
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_Handle()
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args)
   at Com.Tridion.Marketingsolution.Tracking.HandlerBase..ctor(String action, String parameter)
   at Tridion.OutboundEmail.ContentDelivery.Tracking.Handler.HandlerImplementation..ctor(HttpRequest request)
   at Tridion.OutboundEmail.ContentDelivery.Tracking.Handler..ctor(HttpRequest request)
   at Tridion.OutboundEmail.ContentDelivery.Synchronization.Tracking.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: Seems to suggest a missing jar file in Tridion CD - is this a load balanced environment with more than one application? Could one server be set-up right and one not, hence the intermittent error?

Comment: `com.tridion.marketingsolution.tracking.HandlerBase` is part of the `oe_tracking.jar`, a intermittent `ClassNotFoundException` is either a setup issue, or it is indicating another issue which is just masked through this error.

Comment: Those comments should be answers.

Comment: It is a load balanced envirionment, but i tested it on one of the machines and localhost as URL. So it is definitely this server. Restart of the IIS on this machine solved the issue. 

The only thing i can think of is that the connection between .Net and Java (JuggerNET) fails after application pool refreshing multiple times over a long period of time.

Comment: @DominicCronin I placed it as a comment since it can be useful, but I hardly expect it to be *the* answer, if the error was not intermittent then the answer was simple and I would have given it.

Comment: @FuZZbaLL you might be on to something there, but for a possible reason why the connection between .Net and Java (JuggerNET) fails I would not have a clue.

Comment: That's why the Tridion documentation is quite explicit that you should configure your application pool to NOT recycle.

Comment: @FuZZbaLL,  did you get any resolution for your issue as we are also getting same kind of intermittent issue and believe that sometimes juggernet is failing. the issue is solved if we restart the iis. We have already configured the application pool to not recycle, My question is posted at http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8236/intermittent-classnotfoundexception

Comment: @NunoLinhares - we are facing the same kind of issue  but not with audience manager, We have tried disabling the recycle app pool as well as increasing the heap size but nothing seems to work. The major problem is we are not able to replicate it on demand and hence not able to find the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

It may be worth checking the version of Java that you are using.  Only certain versions are supported and proven to work for SDL Tridion 2011.

You may want to check out the answers here (especially Pankaj's answer):
[What versions of Java are supported and proven to work for Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/what-versions-of-java-are-supported-and-proven-to-work-for-tridion-2011-sp1-hr1)