# Commiting deployment failed

Tags: content-delivery, publishing, deployer

I am getting this error since past couple of days while publishing pages having components.

```
Phase: Deployment Commit Phase failed, 
Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-884675-66560, 
Unable to commit transactions, 
Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-884675-66560, 
Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-884675-66560, 
Unable to commit transactions, 
Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-884675-66560, 
Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-884675-66560, 
Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-884675-66560, 
Unable to commit transactions, 
Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-884675-66560, 
Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-884675-66560, 
Unable to commit transactions, 
Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-884675-66560, 
Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-884675-66560
```

However, when I publish a page without any component in it, it gets published successfully. The same component laden page is getting published on one of the servers, but fails to get published on the other one. Please tell me where can I further probe to find a solution. 
Looking at the logs say:

"`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "Session_Preview_QA" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:bfb8b38b-e75c-4c8c-85b3-fdb0c7c46ff4 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerE‌​xception.java:216) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]`" This is the error I see. I am not sure why is it looking for this preview database when I have no site-edit in place and I dont find any entry in config files for this data base.

Comment: You'll have to look at the logs of the environment where it fails. Start by changing logback.xml to be DEBUG (or TRACE if you feel up to it), restart the deployer, publish and then go check for errors/warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced similar issue some time back. reason was wrong java version.

Please check following post [What versions of Java are supported and proven to work for Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/what-versions-of-java-are-supported-and-proven-to-work-for-tridion-2011-sp1-hr1)

and another time it was resolved after applying hotfix from tridion, please check the hotfix on SDL world.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you get a `Commit failed` message for a deployment, it means that the data couldn't be written to whatever storage medium was appropriate. So if it was for every page, I'd start by checking that the process running the deployer/broker had sufficient file system permissions to write the file. In your case, it can write a page without component presentations, so writing the page file doesn't seem to be the problem.

When a component presentation is present on a page, Tridion needs to write metadata so that it can later resolve component links. Perhaps it is this metadata that can't be deployed. These days, it's most likely that it's configured to go in the broker database, although the file system is also a possibility. Check your storage configuration and then manually check that the relevant account can write successfully.

You have noted that there is no logging output. Perhaps this is the first thing you should address. The obvious things to check are:

1. Logback is configured correctly
2. The deployer account has the correct permissions for your logging output location
3. Some versions of Java are broken - one of the symptoms of this is no logging output

Comment: Answer updated to address logging issue

Comment: "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "Session_Preview_QA" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:bfb8b38b-e75c-4c8c-85b3-fdb0c7c46ff4
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]" This is the error I see. I am not sure why is it looking for this preview database when I have no site-edit in place and I dont find any entry in config files for this data base.

Comment: It sounds like you have at least some of it configured. I'd check your config files. I would also check that you haven't got any unnecessary jars in your lib, just in case they are getting loaded and using defaults.